# Dual axis chart from the same measure in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm aware of how to create a dual-axis chart using two different measures for the Y-axis. Is there a way for me to create a dual-axis chart using a same measure but on two different range in the dual-axis? For example, I have a column which contains revenue, I want to create a dual-axis chart where one axis has revenue for Year 2013, and the other with revenue for Year 2014.

**Edit:** my aim is to create a line chart for revenue Year 2013, and bar chart for revenue Year 2014, on the same chart. See picture below is what I have done to have FY13 and FY14 values for each month and running monthly cumulative.

[image]

Now what I wanted to do is to have the two FY13 bar charts to be line charts superimposed on their corresponding FY14 bar charts.

I attach also my Tableau workbook that creates the charts above in the first tab.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5548442/StackOverflow%20attachments/FY13%20vs%20FY14.twbx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Drop the measure in the row shelf.
2. Then grab the same measure with Control key pressed and drop it again on the row shelf.
3. You will have two instance of the same measure on the row shelf.
4. Right Click the second measure on the row shelf and click dual axis.
5. Right click the axis on the worksheet and Edit axis to your choice.

Let me know if this solved your problem.

**EDIT**

Create 2 calculated feild:

1. If [FY] = "FY13"
   then [Value]
   end

call it- 2013
and

2. If [FY] = "FY14"
   then [Value]
   end

call it- 2014

Then just do as i have done in this image.

[image]

Comment: Apologies maybe my question wasn't phrased correctly. Besides the axes being displayed in both sides, I'd like to plot one chart of year 2013 revenue and another of year 2014 revenue. The reason I want to do dual axes is because one chart was meant to be line and the other bar. Your approach does create two axes, but I can't have a different chart for different range of value.

Comment: If you want to change the display type, click the Marks card and choose the drop down for Line and Bar for your respective measure. Can you draw something, and post here. I will try to mimic that.

Comment: I've added screenshot and my workbook, hope those clarify. Thanks for your help!