# Dual axis chart for three measure in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to apply dual axis to three measures, but after following the answer from [Dual axis chart from the same measure in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736734/dual-axis-chart-from-the-same-measure-in-tableau), i found myself stop at 2 measures. I cannot combine the third measure.

Any help is appreciated. Much thanks.

[My Tableau Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jUep.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Simply pull my measure value to the col on the right.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU56j.png)

Comment: Why couldn't you just drop the year dimension on the Color card instead of creating three separate calculated fields?