# Create subset and overall value line chart

Tags: tableau-api

This may sounds very simple but I am finding hard to get that. I have a data with value in one column and category in another column. i.e.,

```
Value Category Month
100     A       Jan
300     A       Feb
200     A       Mar
459     B       Jan
334     B       Feb
765     B       Mar
```

I am trying to use a line chart in tableau with Month on X axis and Value on Y-axis.Basically I am trying to add two lines, one for overall value for that particular month and another line for Category A alone for that particular month. Say for example the overall value for Jan as 559 and another line in same graph for category A for Jan as 100.

Though it sounds so basic, I find hard to achieve this. Should I create a calculated field for this or is there any simple method that works for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want a dual axis probably to achieve this.
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiplemeasures_dualaxes.html

See: [Dual axis chart from the same measure in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736734/dual-axis-chart-from-the-same-measure-in-tableau)

Then you can color one of the measures based upon the category.   Make sure to synchronize axis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The second hyperlink which speaks about creating calculated field worked fine for this situation